# How to resolve Google Cloud Internal DNS names from an on premise DNS server

Tags: dns

Google has Internal DNS service that lets instances in the same network access each other by using internal DNS names which is of the format :
[INSTANCE_NAME].[ZONE].c.[PROJECT_ID].internal

So if there is a vm named "instance1" in zone "us-central1-a" and project "project1", then the dns name for the vm is : "**instance1.us-central1-a.c.project1.internal**" .
So I can do a ping as below from another vm in the same VPC:

$ ping instance1.us-central1-a.c.project1.internal

Below is google documentation on internal dns:
https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns

We would like to do same ping from an on-prem system.

We have Dedicated Interconnect between On-Prem and Google Cloud, and on-prem can communicate to vm's in GCP Network through internal IP.
We want to communicate from on-prem by using Google Cloud internal dns names like "**instance1.us-central1-a.c.project1.internal**".

We are using Windows Server 2012 for on-prem DNS , and Google Cloud DNS.

How can it be done ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a VM in GCP as dns forwarder ( bind .. or any dns service) and forward to google internal dns 169.254.169.254.
From your on-prem DNS forward to VM as dns forwarder